# Why does jQuery's .done() ajax function only work when chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Older versions of jQuery:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
    }
  });
}
```

Current version of jQuery (will work):

```
$.ajax({

    url: "post.php",
    data: {
        id: 123
    },
    method: "GET",
    dataType : "json",
})
  .done(function( json ) {
     $( "<h1>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
     $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
  })
```

Will not work:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "post.php",
    data: {
        id: 123
    },
    method: "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    done: function( json ) {
     $( "<h1>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
     $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
  }
})
```

Comment: Because that's the way the library was implemented? What are you asking? There's no supported "done" property on the `$.ajax()` argument object.

Comment: Because that's how it works. The thing the `ajax` methods returns has a `done` method. The object you pass to `ajax` doesn't consume a `done` property. Are you asking why there was a shift in the approach used?

Comment: Not hard to look this up in the api docs. Is a bit like saying why doesn't `$.ajax().success()` work? Because that's not how it's documented

Comment: It doesn't work *only* when chaining: `var a = $.ajax({...}); a.done(...};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the object parameters are defined by jQuery's [XHR API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and the Promise functions are defined by the [Deferred API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).